# Omitting the "The variable X is declared but never used" from VS build output

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to omit only the missing variable warnings like: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used?
I don't care about these variables.

Comment: If you don't care about them, why did you declare them? The right way to get rid of these warnings is to remove the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this warning is occurring when you are building a C# project (there are very similar ones for other languages), then you can disable it in your project's "Properties".

Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer, and select "Properties" (at or near the bottom of the pop-up menu). Then, in the properties display, select the "Build" tab from the list on the left, and add `168` (you may need to enter the full warning code, `CS0168`) in the "Suppress Warnings" edit box:

[image]

Of course, a *better* way to avoid the warning is not to declare variables that you don't use! However, I understand that this is sometimes useful during developmental and debug stages: and note, this setting is *configuration-specific*, so you could suppress the warning in your "Debug" build but allow it in your (final) "Release" build.

<sup>*If you are using another language (like C++ or C), you can suppress the warning in a very similar manner. I can modify this answer, if that it the case.*</sup>

Comment: Actually I had to use CS0168 because 168 did not work.

Comment: @realPro Odd. Just the number works for me. (Maybe different VS versions?)

Comment: Latest VS c# 4.8

Comment: For me, using `CS0168` also works. VS19 - 16.5.4; and: "C# Tools 3.5.0-beta4-20153-05+20b9af913f1b8ce0a62f72bea9e75e4aa3cf6b0e" (according to the IDE About... box).

Comment: @realPro But thanks for reporting the issue - I've edited my post accordingly.